# How can I make my task run first regardless of the task name passed to gradlew?

Tags: gradle, groovy

I've added this to my project-level build.gradle to make my task, `:birds:generateStringResources`, execute before any other task.

```
tasks.all { Task t ->
    if (t != ':birds:generateStringResources') {
        println("Adding dependsOn(':birds:generateStringResources') to: $t")
        t.dependsOn(':birds:generateStringResources')
    }
}
```

Then I run `./gradlew trees`. From the output, we can see during configuration that `dependsOn(':birds:generateStringResources')` has been added to several (but not all) tasks.

```
> Configure project :
Adding dependsOn(':birds:generateStringResources') to: task ':build'
Adding dependsOn(':birds:generateStringResources') to: task ':assemble'
Adding dependsOn(':birds:generateStringResources') to: task ':buildDependents'
Adding dependsOn(':birds:generateStringResources') to: task ':buildEnvironment'
etc...
```

However, the first task to run is not `:birds:generateStringResources`. After configuration, here's the output:

```
> Task :trees:preBuild UP-TO-DATE // <-- This is the first task being executed. I want `:birds:generateStringResources` to run before any other task.
> Task :trees:preArm64DebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :trees:mergeArm64DebugNativeDebugMetadata NO-SOURCE
> Task :dogs:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
etc...
```

When I run `./gradlew tasks --all`, here's the beginning of the output:

```
> Task :birds:generateStringResources // Success. This is the first task.
> Task :tasks
```

The rest of the build is dependent on these string resources existing, so how can I make `:birds:generateStringResources` run first before *everything* else regardless of the task name passed in after `./gradlew`?

Answer (score 0):

The answer was to add the call to all of the subprojects as well. I dislike the duplication, but it works. Applying it to the project-level build.gradle only covered the project-level tasks.

```
// trees build.gradle
tasks.all { Task t ->
    if (t != ':birds:generateStringResources') {
        println("Adding dependsOn(':birds:generateStringResources') to: $t")
        t.dependsOn(':birds:generateStringResources')
    }
}
```

```
// birds build.gradle
tasks.all { Task t ->
    if (t != ':birds:generateStringResources') {
        println("Adding dependsOn(':birds:generateStringResources') to: $t")
        t.dependsOn(':birds:generateStringResources')
    }
}
```

```
// dogs build.gradle
tasks.all { Task t ->
    if (t != ':birds:generateStringResources') {
        println("Adding dependsOn(':birds:generateStringResources') to: $t")
        t.dependsOn(':birds:generateStringResources')
    }
}
```

etc...

Answer (score 0):

> how can I make :birds:generateStringResources run first before everything else regardless of the task name passed in after ./gradlew?

The code in your build files runs on every invocation of Gradle (ie in the [configuration phase](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_lifecycle.html#sec:build_phases)). The code making up task actions only runs if those tasks are selected, either by name or as dependencies of the of the selected task(s).

Therefore to get a task to run on every build, simply run the code that makes up that task's action from the regular build code.